# Azure Application Gateway Health Probe Error

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

I have an application gateway that is pointed to a .net core api running on an app service

All the endpoints are protected, so I setup a custom health probe to accept 401 as a valid response

However, after I setup the custom health probe and apply it, the status of the backend health stays at "Unhealthy" but the details says "success"

Anyone have any idea what the issue may be?

A sample URI would be: /api/sample/test

Comment: Any update on your side? Is the reply below helpful?

Comment: @NancyXiong yes it was, we setup different probes to be directed to the different paths and expect the correct response code and the gateway showed a healthy status

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Application Gateway Probe is bound to HTTP Settings. So probe to the Backend pool will look something like this (http/https://hostname:HTTPSettingsport/Path)

Try to do a curl to the probe URL and check what response you get. Please post the curl response, based on the response will proceed further.